# Is it possible to add same UIViewController Class to another tab

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Is it possible to added same FirstViewController class to UITabBarController
-> tabBar -> 4 items added.

ZeroTabBarController -> FirstViewController -> FirstViewController -> ThirdTabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do what you are trying to do.

To achieve this, you have to trick it little bit.

Below is what you will structure

```
Tabbar
  - DummyOneVC - FirstVC
  - SecondVC
  - DummyThreeVC - FirstVC
  - FourthVC
```

Now in `DummyOneVC`, in `viewWillAppear` you will transition to `FirstVC` but *without animation* so that user will not know what you are doing behind.

### DummyOneVC

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let destVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVC") as! FirstVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: false)    
}
```